# The conditions for $\lim_{x\to\infty}{g(x)\bar{F}(x)}=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable with distribution $F$, and $g$ is a continuous function such that $E[g(X)]< \infty$. Is
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}{g(x)\bar{F}(x)} = 0
$$
always true, where $\bar{F}(x) = 1-F(x)$ is the survival function? If not, what other conditions should $g$ have?

Comment: $F$ is the CDF right?

Comment: @inavda Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It holds if  $g\colon[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is monotone nondecreasing and $g(x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. To wit,
  $$P[X>x]\leq P[g(X)\geq g(x)]\leq\frac{1}{g(x)}E\big[g(X)\mathbb{1}_{\{g(X)\geq g(x)\}}\big]$$
  to equivalently
  $$
  g(x)E[X>x]\leq g(x)E[g(X)\geq g(x)]\leq E\big[g(X)\mathbb{1}_{\{g(X)\geq g(x)\}}\big]$$
  If $g(X)$ is integrable, then by dominated convergence, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}E\big[g(X)\mathbb{1}_{\{g(X)\geq g(x)\}}\big]=0$$
  whence we conclude that $g(x)E[X>x]\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}0$.
- If $g\colon[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is bounded (not necessarily monotone nondecreasing) the conclusion of the statement in the OP holds trivially.
- It is left to the OP to decide whether the statement holds if $g\colon[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is unbounded but not necessarily monotone nondecreasing.

---

**Edit:** Here is a hint for what I leave to the OP:
Starting from $g(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}e^x\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+\frac1{n^2}]}(x)$ and $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$, one may construct a continuous function $\phi:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ such that $\phi(x) E[X>x]$ diverges as $x\rightarrow\infty$ even though $E[\phi(X)]<\infty$.

Comment: Do you find it an easy exercise to determine what you have left to the reader? I ask because I am curious as well. I have thought about the unbounded non-monotonic case for a while now with no luck.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: One has to think a little, but starting  from this example $g(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}e^{x}\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+n+\tfrac{1}{n^2}]}(x)$ and $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(X)$ one can cook up an example with continuous $\phi$ where $\phi(x)E[X>x]$ does not converge even though $E[\phi(X)]<\infty$. The key is to have a function that oscillates "a lot".

Comment: That’s brilliant, cheers!