# A counterexample on tails of distribution

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

This question is motivated by this innocuous [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4419069/121671)

Suppose $X$ is a nonnegative random variable, $X\neq0$. Is there a measurable function  $\phi:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ such that

1. $\mathbb{E}[\phi(X)]<\infty$.
2. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x)\mathbb{P}[X>x]$ exists and is positive?

---

In the aforementioned posting, the author was asking whether
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x) \mathbb{P}[X>x]=0\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}
whenever $X\geq0$, $X\neq0$ and (1) holds, or conditions on $\phi$ that yield \eqref{three}.

As it can be seen easily,  if either $\phi$ is monotone increasing and $\phi(x)\xrightarrow{x\rightarrow\infty}\infty$, or $\|\phi\|_\infty<\infty$, then \eqref{three} holds; by considering the example $g(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}e^x\mathbb{1}_{(n,n+\varepsilon_n]}(x)$ where $0<\varepsilon_n<1$ and $\sum_n\varepsilon_n<\infty$, and $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(1)$, one can obtain and example of a continuous function $\phi$ for which $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x)\mathbb{P}[X>x]$ does not exist.

---

Although comparing the tails of distribution of $\phi(X)$ and $X$ may not be very common in applications (except in the monotone increasing case by virtue of Chebyshev's inequality)  I think I would be interesting construct and example satisfying (2)

---

Edit: It seems that no such counterexample exits. Let $\mu_X=\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$. Suppose $\phi\geq0$ is such that $\phi(X)$ in itegrable.  Then
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int_{(x,\infty)}\phi(x)\mu_X(dx)=0\tag{4}\label{four}
\end{align}
$$
by dominated convergence. If $\liminf_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi(x)\mu_X((x,\infty))=a>0$, then there is $x_0$ such that
$$ \frac{a}{2}\frac{1}{\mu_X((x,\infty))}<\phi(x)$$
for all $x\geq x_0$. Since $t\mapsto\mu_X((t,\infty))$ is monotone non increasing, for $x\geq x_0$
$$\int_{(x,\infty)}\phi(t)\,\mu_X(dt)\geq \frac{a}{2}\int_{(x,\infty)}\frac{1}{\mu_X((t,\infty))}\mu(dt)\geq\frac{a}{2}$$
This contradicts \eqref{four}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \lim_{x\to\infty}\phi(x)F(x)>0$. Then for $x \geq x_0$ it holds that $\alpha/2 \leq \phi(x)F(x)\leq 2\alpha$. Thus, for $\psi(x)=1/F(x)$, we have $\phi(x) \asymp \psi(x)$ for $x \geq x_0$. Note that $\psi$ is non-decreasing and that $E[\psi(X)]<\infty$, since $\psi(x)\leq \frac{2}{\alpha} \phi(x)+\psi(x_0)$. Then by the case that you already showed, you get a contradiction. Hence, no such $\phi$ can exist.

Comment: Hi PhoemueX, at the time you were posting your answer I was typing a solution that kept lingering over my head for several minutes. Still, I appreciate you answer, which in essence if the same as mine (there is probably the natural way to do it) I will accept your answer.